# Suggestions needed regaring my project!

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, xhtml, joomla

I am planning to build a University Management System using PHP/MYSQL. Should I get started with Joomla/Drupal CMS or Handcode it myself from the scratch?

Your suggestions are invited. Even if you have any other idea which helps me getting my job done in Secure and Fast way please let me know.

Comment: Nowadays - I code everything myself.
This is very subjective question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unorthodox question, and you shouldn't ask it here. Possibly a question for web masters? https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

If not, then I'd say only the experienced coder should make his own CMS unless he's willing to  spend a LONG time on this project learning and read books. If you're just looking to get it done. Try using Wordpress:

http://wordpress.org/

Not just a blog tool, a fantastic CMS from my experience.

Answer (score 2):

First if you want answers you should be precise about your requirements and your skills. All systems including coding from scratch have their advantages depending on the requirements and your abilities.

However I want to say that I disagree with the answer from Jackson and especially nix. For most projects I believe it is a silly idea to build your own system. Many people who are now working with Drupal (or another system) have done that in the past and then realized that they:

- Are not smarter and a better coder than thousands of company's developers combined
- Spend more time maintaining their system than building new features
- made mistakes at the beginning that are hard to fix later (That also happens with existing systems but people spend a lot of time to get things done right e.g. http://drupal.org/node/8 reviewing each others work)

Regarding the points nix made:

1. And unless you something very specific you don't need to. I don't care how every subsystem of my car works either.
2. Agree. If you buy a snowboard, don't try to use it as a bike. Learn snowboarding.
3. Yes but that gets easier nowadays with every system having auto update functionality. Anyway you get bugfixes and new improvements for free - what's the problem?
4. Drupal would also be an exception. Try http://drupalgardens.com (it's free and gets you an idea in just a few minutes) to get an idea without installing something yourself.

Bottom line is: There is no ultimate answer to your question as you have asked it but don't try to reinvent the wheel if it is not needed.